# Is there a HTTPFox for Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, http

Is there an application in Linux that allows me to see all outbound HTTP requests like the HTTPFox Firefox plugin. In case you don't know about HTTPFox, the screenshot below shows what I am looking for.

[image]

**EDIT:**: I want to be able to see the info of any HTTP connection from any application. Not just Firefox.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from using HTTPFox through firefox on your ubuntu install? I just installed the plugin and its running like a champ.

Comment: I meant to ask that I need to be able to view the request headers and response headers, content etc of ANY http connection from any application.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you are trying to do? You can use WireShark and its querying facilities to isolate the source/destination ports and protocols that are relevant to your application(Basically capturing everything that travels through a specific interface). If you limit to HTTP only you will get exactly the same information available in HTTPFox(Headers, encodings, content) plus you'll have access to everything right down to the individual frames on wire.

Comment: I need to view the requests send and the resposne received for many projects I work on from time to time. If wireshark does this, thats exactly what I am looking for. Add the same as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. HTTPfox works fine on Firefox on Linux (including Ubuntu) as far as I know.

If you're looking for something more general, outside the browser, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) can listen to the traffic happening on your network (in particular on your machine). It has a comprehensive set of protocol analysers, including HTTP.

Since it doesn't run within the browser (or other application), it won't be able to see what's going on within the application itself. In particular, it will be harder look into HTTPS traffic, although with some configurations (provided you have the server's private key and you're using a subset of cipher suites Wireshark can decipher), you'll also be able to look into SSL/TLS-encrypted traffic (and the HTTP analyser will work on top of this, in this case).

Answer (score 3):

firebug in firefox has the **net** tab(http://getfirebug.com/network). This shows all the requests and responses received or sent through the browser. A little lower down the chain is [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) which allows filtering by protocol, inspection of individual packets, etc. This seems like it might be a little more robust than you are looking for. I am running these both on my Ubuntu box without an issue.